# Support of convolution in pde

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convolution

Let $f$ be an square-integrable function on a bounded domain U.
Moreover  $\eta(x) = C e^{-\frac {1}{1-x^2}} $ on $[-1,1] $ and 0 elsewhere. C is taken in such a way that the integral over eta is equal to one. Define $\eta_h(x)=\frac{\eta(x/h^n)}{h^n}$. Now my textbook (Evans) says that the convolution of f and $\eta_h$ can only be nonzero on elements in U with distance at least h to the boundary.

Could anybody explain why this is true?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
(f*\eta_h)(x) = \int_{B_h} f(x-y)\,\eta_h(y)\,\mathrm dy
$$
Since $f$ is defined on $U$ only, one requires that $x-y\in U$. Since $y$ runs through $B_h$, this amounts to $|y|<h$. In particular, if $x\in U$ and $\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial U)>h$, this condition is verified.

Comment: Why if $\text{dist}(x,\partial U)> h$, then $x-y\in U$?

Comment: I will give an explanation for a subset $U=[a,b]\subset\mathbb R$, the idea being analogous in higher dimensions, so here $n=1$. The support of $\eta$ is $[-1,1]$ and the one of $\eta_h$ is $[-h,h]$. This means in the above integral can only be nonzero if $|y|<h$. Now if $U=[a,b]$, then the set of points $x$ in $[a,b]$ which have $\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial U)>h$ is given by $(a+h,b-h)$. Therefore, if $x$ is contained in this subset, then $x-y\in U$ provided $|y|<h$.